# Fill missing array elements with zero values for Flot

Tags: php, arrays, flot

I'm creating an array in PHP to send back to the front end for display in a Flot line chart.  I have data that should be displayed year to date by month.  If my SQL statement doesn't find any values for a given month, there is no array element for that month, and the Flot chart doesn't plot a data point for that month (See Mar and Apr in screenshot below). I'd like it to show a zero data point for months where there is no data.

Here's how I'm creating my array:

```
        $array = array();
        $array['data'] = Array();
        $array['label'] = $tags[0]['tag_name'];

        foreach($tags as $key=>$value) {                
            $month = $value['month'];
            $arr = Array($month, $value['trans_amount']);
            array_push($array['data'], $arr);
        }
```

**Current output:**

```
{"data":[[1,"75.00"],[2,"170.00"],[5,"100.00"]],"label":"example label"}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{"data":[[1,"75.00"],[2,"170.00"],[3, "0"],[4, "0"],[5,"100.00"]],"label":"example label"}
```

and here's how the chart currently displays with the current output:

[image]

Comment: Are you getting months 1-5 when you try to output the $month variable?
How does you $tags array look like?

Comment: I'm only getting 1, 2 & 5 because that's the only data in the database.  Nothing needs to change on that end, I just need to modify my PHP to fill in the gaps in the array with zero values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. It's a slight modification of your foreach loop. You need an extra variable $monthVal keep track of the current month.

```
//Assuming this the month uptil which you want the data.
    $current_month = 7;
    $monthVal = 1;
    foreach($tags as $key=>$value) {                
        $month = $value['month'];
        if($month != $monthVal){
            while($month != $monthVal){
                $array['data'][] = Array($monthVal, "0");
                $monthVal += 1;
            }
        }
        $arr = Array($month, $value['trans_amount']);
        array_push($array['data'], $arr);
        $monthVal += 1;
    }
    //This loop is added to append the array if the last entry is not equal to $current_month.
    while($monthVal <= $current_month){
        $array['data'][] = Array($monthVal, "0");
        $monthVal += 1;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to work with one exception:  It doesn't seem to add a zero array element when the last month is empty.  In the example I gave originally, if I were to change the code to where the current month is July, so the last month with data is May, it doesn't add elements for June and July.  I have a variable for the current month ($cur_month) that is available too, that might help get around this.  My initial thought was to wrap the entire thing in a while loop that says while $monthVal <= $cur_month, but that seems to throw an error when I try it.

Comment: @hyphen If I understand you correctly,I think you need data uptil the current month. You can use the $current_month variable after the foreach loop in a new while loop. Check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works in PHP 5.3+):

```
$array = array();
$month_min = $month_max = 0;
foreach($tags as $value) {
    $month = $value['month'];
    $array[$month - 1] = array($month, $value['trans_amount']);
    $month_max = $month;
    if (!$month_min) $month_min = $month;
}

$months = array_values(array_map(function ($v) { return intval($v['month']); }, $tags));
$months_range = range(1, $month_max);

foreach (array_diff($months_range, $months) as $month) {
    $array[$month - 1] = array($month, 0);
}

$result = array(
    'data' => array_slice($array, $month - 1),
    'label' => $tags[0]['tag_name'],
);
print_r(json_encode($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. What I do is check if there is a missing months and then populate that month with zero as value.

```
$currMonth = 1;
foreach($tags as $key=>$value) {                
    $month = $value['month'];
    if($month != $currMonth){
        //if we are missing some months populate that month with zero as value
        while($month != $currMonth){
            array_push($array['data'],Array($currMonth, "0"));
            $currMonth++;
        }
    }
    $arr = Array($month, "'" . $value['trans_amount'] . "'");
    array_push($array['data'], $arr);
    $currMonth++;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your `SQL` query to return more data, if it is stored as a date.
Try to maintain dates as dates rather than integers. PHP and SQL `date` functions are extensive and useful.

This simple `for` loop will fill the array with the missing data from the `SQL` query before the `foreach`.

```
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
    if(!isset($tags[$i])){
       $tags[$i]['month'] = $i;
       $tags[$i]['trans_amount'] = 0;
    }
}
foreach($tags as $key=>$value) {                
    $month = $value['month'];
    $arr = array($month, $value['trans_amount']);
    array_push($array['data'], $arr);
}
```